# how to build release for ios in flutter by windows?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have developed my project in flutter by vsCode and test it on android Emulator and it works fine.now i want to build release for ios.so what are my steps to build ios release in windows os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't build ios release in windows os.
But you can build ios release without mac if you use "CodeMagic".
Please check this a link.
https://codemagic.io/start/

Answer (score 0):

Make iOS package need Mac OS and Xcode, there is no way to build iOS package in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot build flutter ios app on your windows 10. Flutter does not allow that. You need Mac Book and Xcode for that

Answer (score 0):

Only way to take ios build, you need Xcode software which is available in mac.
Renting a MacOS machine in the cloud is an alternative.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to build iOS apps on windows. To build an iOS app, XCode is required and it only works on MacOS.

You can use a tool like [odevio](https://odevio.com/) though which will let you use a MacOS build machine from your Windows computer.